# Using a HorizontalScrollView with ImageView's over Gallery LazyLoad?

Tags: android, lazy-loading, android-gallery

Okay I have an idea and I want to know what you all think.

So for my project I have an gallery. I want to load images into the gallery using Lazyloading But lazyloading doesnt seem to work to well with Gallery. It seems it works better with just having a imageview.

I just cant figure out how to get it to work correctly with Gallery.

I was wondering if I had a horizontalscrollview with many images I need to do this work Can it be efficient?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with just using a simple adapter?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    Gallery gallery = new Gallery(this);
    gallery.setAdapter(new MyApater());

    setContentView(gallery);
}

private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        /** Make sure your list gets populated somehow. */
    List<Integer> mContent = new ArrayList<Integer>()
        {
            mContent.add(R.drawable.d1);
            mContent.add(R.drawable.d2);
            ...
        };

    @Override public int getCount() { return mContent.size(); }
    @Override public Object getItem(int position pos) {
        return mContent.get(pos);
    }
    @Override public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    @Override public View getView(int postition, View view ViewGroup vg) {
        /** Inflate your view here. (using the resource id's of mContent) */
        return (ImageView)findViewById(mContent.get(pos));
    }
}
```

}

EDIT:

Sory if I missed the point, I'm not familier with the term 'lazy loading'.

Comment: Well thats what loazyloading uses a BaseAdapter. I just cant get it to work with the Gallery. Here it is here : https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Comment: What do you mean you `can't get it to work with Gallery?` What is not working about it?

Comment: It use a imageview inside of a listview. I cant figure out how to convert it to a gallery.

Comment: Bwah? What exactly are you trying to place into the gallery?

Answer (score 0):

Look here: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582843/general-question-about-android-gallery-control/7583092#7583092)

This is part of one of my Galleries that is feed with LazyLoadinng. I use a DrawableCache to hold the images that I load from the web. It's working perfect.

Comment: So thats how your BaseAdapter looks for gallery? Where do you use the lazyloading at?

Comment: COuld you show me how yours look with the lazyloading. I had trouble converting it from List to Gallery in getView().

Comment: @user856377 What's the issue? You just inflate what views you would like to display, dump them into a ViewGroup and return the ViewGroup. What do you need help with?

Comment: In the GetView() section...How do i execute the LazyLoader code to retrieve the images and show them in the gallery.. I cant figure out how to convert it from a ListView to Gallery? See what i mean?

Comment: @User856377 Look at my answer again.

Comment: I don't know what LazyLoad library you use - they will offer methods to read and set ImageViews.